# Difference between throw and $pscmdlet.ThrowTerminatingerror()?

Tags: powershell, exception

In PowerShell, what is the difference between `throw $ErrorMsg` and `$PScmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($ErrorMsg)`?

Are they same or different? If they are different which one is preferable?

Answer (score 21):

**`Throw` creates a *script*-terminating (runspace-terminating) error**, whereas **`$PScmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` creates a *statement*-terminating error**.

Note: **These aren't official terms** (the docs currently only vaguely reference *terminating* errors in the abstract, without scope), but they're useful for describing the de-facto behavior.

In short: By default,

- **a *script*-terminating error** terminates the **entire runspace** by default, i.e., the running script and all its callers, with no further statements getting executed; in other words: unless such an error is caught or suppressed, it is **fatal**.

  - They can be *caught* with a **[`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement** (or, less commonly, a [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement).
  - They can be *suppressed* with by setting the **[`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference)** to `'SilentlyContinue'`, or - in PowerShell (Core) 7+ only - to `'Ignore'`.
- whereas **a *statement*-terminating error** terminates **only the current statement** (the function calling `$PScmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` and the statement it is a part of, which is often a *pipeline*), with **execution continuing with the *next* statement** by default.

  - They can be caught or suppressed in the same way that script-terminating errors can, but note that **the [common `-ErrorAction` *parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) has *no* effect on them**.
  - Conversely, you can *promote* them to script-terminating errors with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, despite the docs claiming that `$ErrorActionPreference` pertains only to *nonterminating* errors, the 3rd error type (to which the `-ErrorAction` parameter *exclusively* applies).

For more information, see [this (unofficial) overview of PowerShell's error handling](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

As for **guidance when to use which type of error**:

- There is **little guidance as to when to use `Throw`** in the [`about_Throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw) help topic; an example use case is given in which `Throw` is used to abort a function/script in the absence of a mandatory parameter, as an alternative to PowerShell's default behavior of *prompting* for it.

  - Just be aware that `Throw`, i.e., throwing a *script*-terminating error terminates the entire runspace (the running script and any of its callers), unless caught.
- The [Cmdlet Error Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-error-reporting) article only discusses ***cmdlet-internal* use** with respect to **when to report *statement*-terminating (called just "terminating" in the article) vs. *nonterminating* errors**.

  - A concise summary of the article can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).

Given the latter, you could argue that *advanced functions* - since they're like cmdlets - should *at most* report *statement*-terminating errors and that `Throw` (*script*-terminating errors) should be limited to *scripts*, but note that that contradicts the use of `Throw` to enforce mandatory parameters.

*Perhaps* the problematic distinction between *script*-terminating and *statement*-terminating errors is ultimately *unintentional* and *perhaps* the original intent was to only ever have *script*-terminating ones, which would explain why all the current documentation only ever talks about *terminating* errors in the abstract, without even mentioning the distinction.

Comment: I prefer to use script-terminating errors 99% of the time. That's simply how exceptions are supposed to work. I realize though, since it's a shell, there are some cases were it might make sense to just write to stderr instead, mostly in pipeline situations when processing multiple items. But to me, that's the "exception" - pun intended ;)

Comment: Agreed, @marsze. It wouldn't be officially admitted, but I still suspect that the _statement_-terminating errors were an accident, as also suggested by the fact that the docs never distinguishing between these two subtypes of terminating errors. Whatever the history may be, to me the elimination of statement-terminating errors in favor of only having script-terminating ones makes sense - but it's unlikely that this will happen.